# Eclipse/Zend Studio, stop validation for parts of a project tree

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I have some external libraries that are showing 'warnings', I want to stop validation of this part of my project because it is interfering with actual warning messages from my source code.  Is this possible?

I am using Zend Studio but it is based on eclipse so I think the same method will apply on both applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to go to Preferences/Validation/HTML syntax validator for PHP files/ click on settings. Add first an exclude group and then add a rule with your library folder. This will work at least with pure PHP warnings. I have a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539275/disable-eclipse-validators) concerning DLTK warnings and also posted [this question to ZS forums](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=9041), but I have not too much hope from there.

Comment: Thanks, my workspace had been getting stuck when validating the dojo library in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a dependency we were pulling in and the previous answer didn't help (maybe because it changed in the last 7 years). I found a solution [on the Zend Forums](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=118648).

Word of caution: if your files are having errors, you probably should NOT preform these steps!

To summarize:

1. Right-click on the folder.
2. Click "User As Library Folder"