# disable eclipse validators

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt, dltk

I do have a project which includes ZF library. In the problems tab I get all the warnings from the Zend library. 
My problem is that I want to hide all that.
I've tried adding Exclude Group settings and rules for HTML for PHP validator and even I've suspended all validators for global settings and as a customized project settings and nothing works.
The strange thing is that most common type of problem is DLTK and I cannot find this particular validator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not all things in Eclipse that validate are validators. A lot of validation comes from builders. It is quite easy to disable a builder, but there could be unintended consequences if the builder is supposed to generate artifacts in addition to validation. To disable a builder, go to Project Properties -> Builders and uncheck it.

As an alternative, some tools that include builders allow you to specify that certain types of problems should not be reported. I am not familiar with PHP tools, but I would poke around under preferences.

Comment: I deactivated all the builders and made a build but I still have listed the problems. I attached also a picture to make it clearer what I am talking about.

Comment: Problems are persistent. They don't go away if the builder that added them is deactivated. To make them go away, remove the projects from the workspace (take care not to delete it). Then add it back again. That will loose persisted problems.